# Custom separator in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, separator

I have my own separator in .jpg and would like to use it instead of default one in TableView, but the only thing I get is that it disappears.

Swift 3.0:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "musicCell", for: indexPath) as! SongTableViewCell

    let color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Separator.jpg")!)
    let separator = tableView.separatorColor(color)

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bckgrd.jpg"))
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
    //tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Separator.jpg"))
```

This is one of the ways I've tried to implement. Is there other way to do that?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: that seems messy. why do you configure the `tableview`'s _footer_ and _background_ in the delegate method every time when you are supposed to focus on the current cell only?

Comment: 1)Add customview in tableview cell. and add image in customview.height should be 1 of this view.and add your image to this imageview

Comment: 2)in tableview select No in separator and make separator color clear color.and cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set separator style also not color only. Set `separator style` to `single line` and make sure that your `Separator.jpg` image looks like single line and you are getting color by `let color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Separator.jpg")!)` this statement!

you can set seperator style something like,

```
 tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
```

P.S : If you are checking this on simulator then check it in full resolution (i.e. `cmd + 1` or in simulator `window - > scale - > 100%`), becasue sometime actually there is no problem but because of smaller scale you can't see it

**Update :**

Another way : `Set SeparatorStyle to None` from interface builder or by code like,

```
   tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

then you can add `seperator image`(imageview of height 1 pixel or 2 pixel) to cell at bottom in content view of cell by code or interface builder like,

```
   let seperatorImageView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "yourseperatorimg.jpg"))
    seperatorImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0,  cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(seperatorImageView)
```

Comment: Everything is checked and added, in inspector properties of separator are by default, and scale didn't change anything as well...damn

Comment: what is the color of your image ?

Comment: this is not image. it's open a webpage!

Comment: I know, I just uploaded it on website, because I don't know how to add the picture to comment

Comment: Unbelievable! :-) It works! Besides one thing that it was showed before that CGRectMake is unavailable in Swift, so I just change it to this:

        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10,y :0), size: CGSize(width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width, height: 1))

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Set separator color on `viewDidLoad` method...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Separator.jpg")!)
    tableView.separatorColor = color
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Separator.jpg")!)
    tblView.separatorColor = color
}
```

Comment: Select table view in ibinspector and set separator to default.

Comment: Yes, everything is on default

Comment: Simulator or device?

Comment: Show cell separator is enabled?

Comment: I guess yes, because they are available unless I'm using .none
btw, I tried to change the picture format to .png and now separators are not showed at all